# unique entries vertically in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I add photos to photo galleries as

```
CREATE TABLE galleries
(
gallery_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
PRIMARY KEY (gallery_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci


CREATE TABLE gallary_map
(
gallery_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
image_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(gallery_id) REFERENCES galleries(gallery_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(image_id) REFERENCES images(image_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (gallery_id,image_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

How can I avoid the creation of duplicate galleries (with the same set of photos in gallary_map)?

Of course, since `galleries` entry should be created before adding the photos to the map, I mean controlling the whole collection to avoid having duplicate galleries.

Comment: What or who forces you to create duplicates? Are you asking about your front-end behavior?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicate galleries the data would be redundant not duplicate

Comment: @PM77-1 how should the end-users should know that a gallery (a specific collection of photos) exists, not to create it?

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja we may have 100 galleries containing image 59 and 77 (only), for example.

Comment: This is not a database question but rather your programming logic. For example, you can store gallery_id in the image table to enforce 1-to-1 relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really feasible or advisible to prevent this, since the duplication could be temporary.

Suppose you create a gallery with images 1 and 2. Then you want to make a second gallery with images 1, 2, and 3. Between adding 3 to the second gallery, it will be a duplicate of the first gallery, and you would be blocked. When creating the second gallery you would have to add them in a different order to avoid this.

But even that could be impossible. Suppose you have 3 galleries:

- Gallery 1 = images 1 and 2
- Gallery 2 = images 1 and 3
- Gallery 3 = images 2 and 3

Now, no matter what order you use, you can't create

- Gallery 4 = images 1, 2, and 3

The any of the first two images will be a duplicate of one of the other galleries.

While MySQL has transactions to group queries, there's no mechanism to delay constraint checking until the end of a transaction.

If you have a procedure to create a gallery all at once, you could perform a query first to check whether it duplicates another gallery exactly. E.g.

```
SELECT SUM(image_id IN (1, 2, 3)) = 3 AND COUNT(*) = 3 AS is_duplicate
FROM gallery_map
GROUP BY gallery_id
HAVING is_duplicate = 1
```

If this returns a row, you already have a gallery with exactly those images, and you can report the problem to the user.

If you want to find duplicates that already exist, you could use:

```
SELECT a.gallery_id, b.gallery_id
FROM (SELECT gallery_id, GROUP_CONCAT(image_id ORDER BY image_id) AS images
      FROM gallery_map
      GROUP BY gallery_id) AS a
JOIN (SELECT gallery_id, GROUP_CONCAT(image_id ORDER BY image_id) AS images
      FROM gallery_map
      GROUP BY gallery_id) AS b ON a.gallery_id < b.gallery_id AND a.images = b.images
```

Comment: 1. what if `INSERT` of all entries into gallery_map occur in one query? 2. how to check if the same set already exists? or 3. how to find and delete duplicate entries (when the gallery is finalised)?

Comment: 1. There's nothing that checks constraints only at the end of the query. 2. I answered that already.

Comment: 3. I added a query to find duplicates to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There aint going to be any duplicates but redundant data

Furthermore if you want to filter the redundant data as distinct columns use group by and aggregate records to get distinct galleries records.

You can manipulate the records though when you are inserting as if image not exists in (other galleries) then insert or use a trigger on insert. Somewhat like a below sample if the new image on insert doesnt exists in any gallery then insert.

```
   Create Trigger Name Before Insert
   On table for each row as

   If(Select gallery from table where 
   imageid =new.imageid) 
  then

  Else
   Insert into...... 

  End IF
  End
```

Comment: imagine each gallery is a webpage showing its photos. Then, I may have millions of duplicate pages according to Google. I cannot group, as each page is created by looking up the gallery_id first.

Comment: Then you got to change your tables structural design add one more column that makes the design atleast relevant

Comment: @Googlebot: You are talking about a *presentation* layer.